# Python: how to decode bytestream string on the server side

Tags: php, python, json, encoding, bytestream

I send my JSON using `urllib.request` on Python 3.

```
data = {"a": "1"}
req = urllib.request.Request('https://example.com', data=json.dumps(data).encode('utf8'), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

The problem is `data=json.dumps(data).encode('utf8')` which converts `{"a": "1"}` to the same string with a `b` prefix `b'{"a": "1"}'`.

I know that in python I can use `decode('utf8)` to remove the `b` prefix, but I need to be able to do this on the server side, because python 3 forces you to send byte stream data.

I use php as the server side code.
I tried using `utf8_decode()` but it doesn't do anything.

How can I remove the `b` prefix on the server side code?

Comment: json.dumps to json.load, can use ast.literal_eval if haven't any error.

Comment: can you rephrase what you said?

Answer (score 0):

The server Side is PHP right? You can try use `utf8_decode()` function. Try and see if this function solve your problem.

```
$data = utf8_decode($data_from_python);
```

Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Comment: Didn't change anything

Comment: The problem is the PHP is considerind the `b` prefix as part of the string, so, to PHP everything is alright. I think you need apply some string funcitons to do this dirty job

Comment: It looks like http://php.net/manual/bg/function.unicode-decode.php could do the trick. But its only for php 6+

Comment: I prefer to do this the right way, and not to manually remove the b prefix

Comment: I prefer that too, but for now, i don't know any function to do that. :(

Comment: Check if this work for you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php

Comment: Didn't change anything